# What can Tabs.star in Joomla 3.1?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in**

```
$options=array('startOffset' => 0,)
echo JHtml::_('tabs.start', '', $options);      
echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', JText::_('TABS_MATCHDETAILS'), 'panel1' );
echo $this->loadTemplate('matchdetails');
echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', JText::_('TABS_SCOREDETAILS'), 'panel2' );
echo $this->loadTemplate('scoredetails');
echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', JText::_('TABS_ALTDECISION'), 'panel3' );
echo $this->loadTemplate('altdecision');
echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', JText::_('TABS_MATCHREPORT'), 'panel4' );
echo $this->loadTemplate('matchreport');
echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', JText::_('TABS_MATCHPREVIEW'), 'panel5' );
echo $this->loadTemplate('matchpreview');
echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', JText::_('TABS_MATCHRELATION'), 'panel6' );
echo $this->loadTemplate('matchrelation');
echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', JText::_('TABS_EXTENDED'), 'panel7' );
echo $this->loadTemplate('matchextended');
echo JHtml::_('tabs.end');
```

Thanks for the answers

Comment: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=764081

Comment: Please bring a small part of my code as an example. I am a novice web master

Comment: Updated my answer - there's a semi-colon missing on the first line

Answer (score 2):

Firstly JPane was deprecated in Joomla 2.5 - so whilst its available to use there you should be using it. For a 2.5/3.1 component/site you should use JHtml Tabs. See the docs page [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JHtmlTabs_class_in_a_component) for instructions on how to use it.

In your specific case something like:

```
$options=array('startOffset' => 9,);
echo JHtml::_('tabs.start', '', $options);
echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', JText::_('COM_JOOMLEAGUE_EDIT_EVENTS_EDIT_HOME_SUBST'), '');
    echo $this->loadTemplate('edit_home_substitution');

echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', JText::_('COM_JOOMLEAGUE_EDIT_EVENTS_EDIT_HOME_PLAYER'), '');
    echo $this->loadTemplate('edit_home_player');
echo JHtml::_('tabs.end');
```

Note also that bootstrap pane's exist as of Joomla 3.0 (and will probably replace JHtml tabs in Joomla 4.0 (still a long way away) which are used in a more similar way to JPane - however these aren't particularly well documented yet - So I'd advise sticking with JHtml tabs for now